# Can this be done in SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Given this data set:

```
SummaryID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6    Q7    Q8    Q9    Q10    Q11    Q12    Q13    Q14    Q15
25           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     6     5     4      3      2      1      2      3
25           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     6     5     4      3      2      1      2      3
25           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     6     5     4      3      2      1      2      3
```

can the data be PIVOTed or CUBEd or whatever into this:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
Q1        3      
Q2            3     
Q3                3    
Q4                    3   
Q5                        3  
Q6                            3 
Q7                                3
Q8                            3 
Q9                        3  
Q10                   3   
Q11               3
Q12           3  
Q13       3  
Q14           3 
Q15               3
```

Essentially, the top table represents how feedback data is stored for a feedback system.  Multiple reviewers are asked to rate a single reviewee on a scale from 0 to 7 for 15 questions.  My example is a rather unlikely set of responses from 3 reviewers in order to show the pattern in the display table

The second table is how I want to display the data.  Each "3" in the table represents the COUNT of responses for the given Q# and Rating combination.  E.g., for Q5, 3 reviewees rated this person a "5".

Clearly, the real data will be much more scattered about.

I'm hoping this is easy.

Thanks,

John Anderson

EDITED: here is my own first attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SummaryID, COUNT(Q1) AS Q1 FROM SummaryData WHERe SummaryID = 25
GROUP BY SummaryID) o
PIVOT (COUNT(Q1) FOR Q1 IN ([0], [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) p

SummaryID   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
25          0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

I'm getting a 1 under the 3, which is not right, and I can't figure out how to extrapolate the code to include all the other Qs.

Thanks again,

John Anderson

EDITED: here is a sample dataset that I modeled in Excel to give results that will more closely resemble reality

```
SummaryID   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5   Q6   Q7   Q8   Q9   Q10   Q11   Q12   Q13   Q14   Q15
25          1    4    5    7    4    2    0    2    1    0     2     2     3     5     0
25          4    1    1    5    6    7    7    4    0    1     3     7     3     1     1
25          5    3    2    1    7    7    4    0    1    6     7     3     2     7     1
```

Results in:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
Q1        1           1   1        
Q2        1       1   1            
Q3        1   1           1        
Q4        1               1       1
Q5                    1       1   1
Q6            1                   2
Q7    1               1           1
Q8    1       1       1            
Q9    1   2                        
Q10   1   1                   1    
Q11           1   1               1
Q12           1   1               1
Q13           1   2                
Q14       1               1       1
Q15   1   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to UNPIVOT first to get data into a format you need, and then PIVOT

Working sample:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Feedback Table 
(
SummaryId INT,
Q01 INT,    Q02 INT,    Q03 INT,    Q04 INT,    Q05 INT,
Q06 INT,    Q07 INT,    Q08 INT,    Q09 INT,    Q10 INT,
Q11 INT,    Q12 INT,    Q13 INT,    Q14 INT,    Q15 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Feedback Values (25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO @Feedback Values (25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO @Feedback Values (25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3)

;WITH ReOrderedData AS
(
SELECT SummaryId, QuestionNum, Score, COUNT (*) as NumScores FROM
(
    SELECT SummaryId, Q01, Q02, Q03, Q04, Q05, Q06, Q07, Q08, Q09, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15
    FROM @Feedback
) p
UNPIVOT (Score For QuestionNum IN (Q01, Q02, Q03, Q04, Q05, Q06, Q07, Q08, Q09, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15)) as UnPvt
GROUP BY SummaryId, QuestionNum, Score)
SELECT QuestionNum, 
    IsNull ([0], '') [0], IsNull ([1], '') [1], IsNull ([2], '') [2], IsNull ([3], '') [3], 
    IsNull ([4], '') [4], IsNull ([5], '') [5], IsNull ([6], '') [6], IsNull ([7], '') [7]
FROM (
SELECT QuestionNum, Score, NumScores
FROM ReOrderedData
) As SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Max (NumScores) For Score IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) As Pivotx
```

Answer (score 0):

not very elegant, but try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table(SummaryID int,Q1 int ,Q2 int ,Q3 int ,Q4 int ,Q5 int ,Q6 int ,Q7 int ,Q8 int ,Q9 int ,Q10 int ,Q11 int ,Q12 int ,Q13 int ,Q14 int ,Q15 int)

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES(25,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES(25,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES(25,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES(25,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)


SELECT
    'Q'+CONVERT(varchar(2),Question) AS Question
    , CASE WHEN Value0=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value0) END AS Value0
    , CASE WHEN Value1=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value1) END AS Value1
    , CASE WHEN Value2=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value2) END AS Value2
    , CASE WHEN Value3=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value3) END AS Value3
    , CASE WHEN Value4=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value4) END AS Value4
    , CASE WHEN Value5=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value5) END AS Value5
    , CASE WHEN Value6=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value6) END AS Value6
    , CASE WHEN Value7=0 THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(5),Value7) END AS Value7
    FROM (
            SELECT
                Question
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value0),0) AS Value0
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value1),0) AS Value1
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value2),0) AS Value2
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value3),0) AS Value3
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value4),0) AS Value4
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value5),0) AS Value5
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value6),0) AS Value6
                , ISNULL(SUM(Value7),0) AS Value7
                FROM (
                      SELECT
                          1 AS Question
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q1=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q3=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q4=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q5=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q6=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          7
                          ,CASE WHEN Q2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q7=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          8
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q8=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          9
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q9=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          10
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q10=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          11
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q11=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          12
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q12=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          13
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q13=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          14
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q14=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT
                          15
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value0
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value1
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value2
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value3
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value4
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value5
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value6
                          ,CASE WHEN Q15=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value7
                          FROM @YourTable
                     ) dt
                GROUP BY Question
         )dt2
    ORDER BY dt2.Question
```

OUTPUT:

```
Question Value0 Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6 Value7
-------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
Q1       3                           1                    
Q2              3                    1                    
Q3                     3             1                    
Q4                            3      1                    
Q5                                   4                    
Q6                                   1      3             
Q7                                   1             3      
Q8                                   1                    3
Q9                                   1             3      
Q10                                  1      3             
Q11                                  4                    
Q12                           3      1                    
Q13                    3             1                    
Q14             3                    1                    
Q15      3                           1                    

(15 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: we worked in SQL Server 7 for years after everyone upgraded, I sometimes still "think" with a limited set of commands...